# php - nothing is displayed due to a php error

Tags: php

I just started learning PHP so recently and I was just following up with a tutorial until I encountered this error.

**with the php just the way it is the page displays nothing even though it worked perfectly in the tutorial video.**

I also found many questions similar to mine but I couldn't really apply it to my code.

*anyway, I'm gonna cut to the chase*

**That's the code**

```
if (  !isset( $_POST['fix_submit'] ) ) {

        $clickbait = strtolower $_POST["clickbait_headline"];

        // grab value from textarea in $_POST collection
        // make all letters lowercase using strtolower() function
        // store in a variable

        $fake = array(
                "doctors",
                "scientists",
                "shocked me",
                "won't believe",
                "will never believe",
                "hate"
            );
        $replaceFake = array(
                "so-called doctors",
                "so-called scientists",
                "was like the others",
                "will find normal",
                "won't be surprised",
                "aren't threatened by"
            );

        $honestHeadline = str_replace ($fake, $replaceFake, $clickbait  );

    }
```

**the whole error is with the first line** because whenever I remove it the page displays the html but obviously the php won't work.

---

**Edit**

after fixing that syntax error it fixed the part about nothing being displayed so thanks for the help.

now it says

> Undefined index: clickbait_headline  on line 8

and when I click the submit button nothing happens
anyway, that's the whole code

```
<?php 

    define ("TITLE", "Honest Click Bait Headline");


    if (  !isset(  $_POST['fix_submit'] ) ) {

        $clickBait = strtolower ($_POST["clickbait_headline"]);

        // grab value from textarea in $_POST collection
        // make all letters lowercase using strtolower() function
        // store in a variable

        $fake = array(
                "doctors",
                "scientists",
                "shocked me",
                "won't believe",
                "will never believe",
                "hate",
                "hack",
                "simple"

            );
        $replaceFake = array(
                "so-called doctors",
                "so-called scientists",
                "was like the others",
                "will find normal",
                "won't be surprised",
                "aren't threatened by",
                "common knowledge",
                "well-known"
            );

        $honestHeadline = str_replace ($fake, $replaceFake, $clickBait  );
    } 
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

    <head>

        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">



        <title><?php echo TITLE; ?></title>


        <!--bootstrap CSS-->
        <link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">

        <!-- Custom styles -->
        <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet">


    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="container">

            <h1><?php echo TITLE; ?></h1>
            <p class="lead">hate click baits? Turn those annoying headlines into realistic and honest ones.</p>
            <div class="row">
                <form class="col-sm-7 col-sm-offset-2" action="" method="post">
                    <textarea class="form-control input-lg" name="clickbait_headline" rows="2" placeholder="Paste clickbait headline here"></textarea><br>
                    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg pull-right" type="submit" name="fix_submit">Make Honest!</button>
                </form>
            </div>
            <?php   if (!isset( $_POST["fix_submit"])) {

                    echo  "<strong class='text-danger'>Original Headline</strong> <h4>".ucwords($clickBait)."</h4><hr><br> ";   // ucwords() to uppercase first letter in every word

                    echo "<strong class='text-success'>Honest Headline</strong> <h4>".ucwords($honestHeadline)."</h4>";

            }
             ?>

        </div>

    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: white screen of death: error checking\display are off, turn them on to see the error. at the top of your php page add: `ini_set('display_errors', 'On'); ini_set('html_errors', 0); error_reporting(-1);`

Comment: post more codes about the form

Comment: `strtolower` is a function, use parenthesis. `$clickbait = strtolower( $_POST["clickbait_headline"]);` voting to close as typo.

Comment: @KrisRoofe  
I edited the question with the whole code and updates

Answer (score 0):

replace `$clickbait = strtolower $_POST["clickbait_headline"];`

with

```
$clickbait = strtolower($_POST["clickbait_headline"]);
```